# How to connect to an exising Azure SQL Database from a Web/Mobile App?

Tags: azure

I wanted to add the Mobile app features to my Web app from the new Azure portal, and I'm not sure what to put for the values when it asks for Connection String settings of the database.

All the documentation shows how to create a new database, but none show the step to connect to an existing database.

Specifically at this step what values do I put for Name, User Name and Password in the Connection String settings after selecting the existing database?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just need to stop you in your tracks right there. You do not connect directly to a database from a mobile app. That is very, very poor design. Assume that you have 50 people using your app every day and you're already in deep financial trouble because keeping that number of connections up requires a more expensive server, and it is a solution that does not scale well at all.

Consider instead writing an API in front of your database. It can be as simple as a WebApi project that you can give your mobile app data from. This scales WAY better, you can do caching in your API, and using API management, you can even provide access policies that are FAR better than simply doing a direct connect.

So even though it is possible, please don't do it. It's a bad, bad software decision.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the same thing I am doing?  Why does Azure allow for Mobile App service if it's use is bad software practice?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Microsoft does allow for Mobile apps as a simple way of getting started with a concept, but if you're planning on going large scale, then this won't scale to fit your needs. For an in-house mobile app used by a few (up to 100 people or so) it is perfect. Beyond that, it is seriously bad practice.

Comment: So just to make sure I'm on the right track is what you suggest a combination of these two example?  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application  AND https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/

Comment: Yes that is the better way to do it (the second link)

Answer (score 1):

You can login from old portal https://manage.windowsazure.com.

1) Click service 'SQL database'

2) You will see a sql server list including the sql server you want to connect. Click button 'Server' above the list to show server.

3) Click the your server name.

4) Click 'Dashboard'. You will see link 'Reset Admin Password'. Click to reset a new password.It seems you can't find the old db password in portal. If you don't know you have to reset.

5) Click 'Database'. You will see your sql server database.

6）Click the sql server your want to connect.

7) Click link 'XXX connection string XXX'. In the connection string, you can find the user name.

8) Now your have already know the user name and reset your password. You can click the link 'Design your SQL database' to login your database.